# Compiling OpenMCU in Linux (Fedora12)

Tags: gcc

I am tring to compile OpenMCU in fedora 12. Since the orignal project was compiled in VC++, it has some compatiility issues with gcc.
I am using gcc 4.4.4 and febora 12.
The error shows somehting like this.

```
In file included from mcu.h:84,
             from main.cxx:56:
filemembers.h:123: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘deque’ with no type
filemembers.h:123: error: typedef name may not be a nested-name-specifier
filemembers.h:123: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘<’ token
filemembers.h:124: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘FilenameList’ with no type
filemembers.h:124: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘&’ token
In file included from mcu.h:84,
             from main.cxx:56:
filemembers.h:149: error: ‘FilenameList’ does not name a type
make: *** [obj_linux_x86_r/main.o] Error 1
```

when checked in the source code of that perticular file it was something like this...

```
class ConferenceFileMember : public ConferenceMember
{
    PCLASSINFO(ConferenceFileMember, ConferenceMember);
    public:
    ConferenceFileMember(Conference * conference, const PFilePath & _fn, PFile::OpenMode mode);

    *typedef std::deque<PFilePath> FilenameList;                 //Line 123..*
    ConferenceFileMember(Conference * conference, const FilenameList & _fns, PFile::OpenMode mode);

    ~ConferenceFileMember();

    void Unlisten();
```

Seems to be a simple syntax issue. Can someone help me in this regards?

Thanx in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like std::deque is not defined.  Did you `#include <deque>`?